# Find the solutions to $z^3 = 2 + 11i$.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> Find the solutions to $z^3 = 2 + 11i$.

---

I wrote $z = x + iy$ to get
$(x + iy)^3 = 2+ 11i$.

Expanding and equating the real and Imaginary parts I got,

$$x^3 - 3xy^2 = 2$$
$$y^3 - 3x^2y = 11$$

Let $tx = y$, Substituting this I got,

$$x^3 - 3t^2x^3 = 2$$
$$x^3(3t-t^3) = 11$$

Susbtituting for $x^3$ from first equation into second eaution I got,

$$2t^3 + -6t - 33t^2 + 11 = 0$$

I don't know how to solve this cubic, I tried finding roots by putting different numbers but I can't find any of them.

What are some other ways of solving without running into a cubic and how can I solve this cubic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your number has norm 125. The answer has norm 5. If they intended integers, that means either $\pm1 \pm 2 i$ or $\pm 2 \pm i.$ Try them.

As 11 is odd, we need $y = \pm 1,$ so $\pm 2 \pm i.$

Comment: What is norm ? I see 5 wikipedia pages for norm.

Comment: @A---B magnitude squared. $11^2 + 2^2 = 125 = 5^3$

Comment: Yes got the answer.

Comment: Nice!  I suppose we could've also used rational roots theorem @A---B XD

Answer (score 2):

To avoid cubics, we use trig:  $\theta=\arctan(11/2)$ and $r=\sqrt{11^2+2^2}=5\sqrt5$

The cube roots are then given as follows:

$$z^3=2+11i=r\operatorname{cis}(\theta)=re^{i\theta}$$

$$z=\sqrt[3]{r}\operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{\theta+2\pi k}3\right)=\sqrt[3]{r}e^{i\frac{\theta+2\pi k}3}$$

Where $\operatorname{cis}(\theta)=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ and $k\in\mathbb N$.

In general, the $n$th roots are:

$$z^n=2+11i$$

> $$z=\sqrt[n]{r}\operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{\theta+2\pi k}n\right)$$

Comment: why arctan(11/2) ? not something else.

Comment: @A---B Since $2+11i$ lies in the 1st quadrant, it follows that the angle between that point and the real axis is given by $\arctan(11/2)$.  Draw a picture to see this :D.  It then follows amazingly that raising complex numbers to powers is equivalent to raising their magnitude by that power and appropriately multiplying or dividing the angles, accounting for $2\pi k$ modulus for rational powers like 1/3 (a.k.a. cube roots)

Comment: I would have selected your answer if using polar form was allowed.

Comment: @A---B Lol, personally, spotting the rectangular form is almost always preferred.  Polar is too easy :P

Comment: No doubt polar is easy. All hail to De Moivre.

Answer (score 2):

> Expanding and equating the real and Imaginary parts I got,
>
> $$x^3 - 3xy^2 = 2 \tag{1}$$
> $$y^3 - 3x^2y = 11$$

The second equation lost a sign along the way, it should be:

$$y^3 - 3x^2y = -11 \tag{2}$$

Subtracting $(1)-(2)$ and grouping:

$$x^3-y^3 - 3xy(y-x)=13 \;\iff\; (x-y)(x^2+4 xy+y^2) = 13$$

Looking for "nice" integer solutions leaves only $x-y=\pm 1,\pm 13$ to try.

Comment: "Looking for "nice" integer solutions leaves only $x−y=±1,±13$ to try." reason for this ? why not $\pm 26, \pm 52$ etc ?

Comment: @A---B $\pm1,\pm13$ are the only divisors of $13\,$.

Comment: Oh my question was vague. I want to know why we need divisors of 13 not multiples ?

Comment: @A---B *If* $x,y$ are integers, then $x-y$ and $x^2+4xy+y^2$ are both integers, and they must both be divisors of $13$ since their product is $13$. But $13$ is a prime number, and its only divisors are $\pm1,\pm13$. The above does *not* prove that $x,y$ must be integers, only that *if* they are then they can be found by verifying a few simple cases.