# Question on Cardano's Method of Solving Cubic Polynomial Equations

Tags: polynomials

I'm having trouble with part of a question on Cardano's method for solving cubic polynomial equations. This is a multi-part question, and I have been able to answer most of it. But I am having trouble with the last part.  I think I'll just post here the part of the question that I'm having trouble with.

We have the depressed cubic equation :
\begin{equation}
f(t) = t^{3} + pt + q = 0
\end{equation}
We also have what I believe is the negative of the discriminant :
\begin{equation}
D = 27 q^{2} + 4p^{3}
\end{equation}
We assume $p$ and $q$ are both real and $D < 0$. We also have the following polynomial in two variables ($u$ and $v$) that results from a variable transformation $t = u+v$ :
\begin{equation}
u^{3} + v^{3} + (3uv + p)(u+v) + q = 0
\end{equation}
You also have the quadratic polynomial equation :
\begin{equation}
x^{2} + qx - \frac{p^{3}}{27} = 0
\end{equation}
The solutions to the 2-variable polynomial equation satisfy the following constraints :
\begin{equation}
u^{3} + v^{3}  = -q 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
uv  = -\frac{p}{3}
\end{equation}
The first section of this part of the larger question asks to prove that the solutions of the quadratic equation are non-real complex conjugates. Here the solutions to the quadratic are equal to $u^{3}$ and $v^{3}$ (this relationship between the quadratic polynomial and the polynomial in two variables was proven in an earlier part of the question). I was able to do this part. The second part of this sub-question is what I'm having trouble with.

The question says, let :
\begin{equation}
u  = r\cos(\theta) + ir\sin(\theta) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v  = r\cos(\theta) - ir\sin(\theta)
\end{equation}
The question then asks the reader to prove that the depressed cubic equation has three real roots :
\begin{equation}
2r\cos(\theta) \text{ , } 2r\cos\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{3} \right) \text{ , } 2r\cos\left( \theta + \frac{4\pi}{3} \right)
\end{equation}
In an earlier part of the question they had the reader prove that given :
\begin{equation}
\omega = \frac{-1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{equation}
s.t. :
\begin{equation}
\omega^{2} = \frac{-1 - i\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{equation}
and :
\begin{equation}
\omega^{3} = 1
\end{equation}
that if $(u,v)$ is a root of the polynomial in two variables then so are :
$(u\omega,v\omega^{2})$ and $(u\omega^{2},v\omega)$. I think that the part of the question I'm having trouble with is similar. I suspect that :
\begin{equation} 
2r \cos\left( \theta + \frac{2\pi}{3} \right) = u\omega + v\omega^{2} \text{ or } u\omega^{2} + v\omega \tag{1}
\end{equation}
and :
\begin{equation} 
2r \cos\left( \theta + \frac{4\pi}{3} \right) = u\omega + v\omega^{2} \text{ or } u\omega^{2} + v\omega \tag{2}
\end{equation}
I have derived that :
\begin{equation}
\omega = \cos(\phi) + i\sin(\phi)
\end{equation}
where $\phi = \frac{2\pi}{3}$. Also :
\begin{equation}
\omega^{2} = \cos(2\phi) + i \sin(2\phi)
\end{equation}
So that the goal of the question may be to prove equations $(1)$ and $(2)$. I have tried to do this but haven't been able to.

Am I approaching this question in the correct way ? If I am approaching it the right way can someone show me how to use trigonometric identities to prove equations #1 and #2 ?

Comment: You just have to remind that $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ are conjugate.

Comment: Is this really Cardano's technique?  It seems to use a fair amount of complex analysis and analytic geometry, which feels much more modern to me (at least post Descartes for the analytic geometry; maybe post Euler or Fourier for the complex analysis?).  Do you have a source for this approach?

Comment: @XanderHenderson: As far as I know, what we now call complex numbers were invented by Cardano-Tartaglia precisely  to have solutions for the ‘impossible  case’ of the method.

Comment: @Bernard Indeed, but my understanding is that the polar form of complex numbers were not understood until much later or used until much later.

Comment: Certainly, but cubic roots of unity were known, I believe (not necessarily under that name).

Comment: [Wikipedia seems to suggest that the trigonometry involved in the solution above is due to Euler and/or de Moivre.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#History)

Comment: @Bernard I doubt that Cardano and Tartaglia had any knowledgew about complex numbers, and certainly they did not know Moivre's formula. They only treated the case $D > 0$ in which we have one real and two complex conjugate solutions. The real solution can be expressed via **real square and cubic roots**. This is impossible if $D < 0$ ("casus irreducibilis") where we have three real roots. In that case it is unavoidable to express the solutions as real parts of complex numbers with nontrivial imaginary part.

Comment: @XanderHenderson This seems plausible!

Comment: @PaulFrost: Cardano was one of the first mathematician to imagine square roots of negative numbers (ca 1545), which were then called *impossible numbers*, and their use was systematised by Rafaelle Bombelli in his *Algebra* treatise (1572).

Comment: @Bernard Okay, but even Cardano had an idea about square roots of negative numbers, he was not able to derive solutions in the casus irreducibilis. He did not explain **how** the solution was found. He only got a poem by Tartaglia describing the formula. See [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/alfonso/347/Tartagliaspoem.pdf). In particular it was not explictly mentioned how $u,v$ can be computed. But perhaps it was clear to him that a quadratric equation has to be solved.

Comment: I think the real work was done by Bombelli. Anyway, we must not forget that the algebraic notations with letter, as we know them;, were invented by François Viète only at the end of the 16th century. When Cardano mentioned the ‘impossible numbers’, Viète was 5 years old.

Comment: @Bernard You are right! While Cardano said that his formula fails in the casus irreducibilis (probably because he did not know the general concept of complex numbers), Bombelli correctly performed calculations with complex numbers and noticed that in some special cases Cardono's formula works by giving real solutions via complex numbers. For the equation $x^3 = 15x +4$ he obtained (in modern terms) $x = \sqrt[3]{2+ \sqrt{-121}} +  \sqrt[3]{2- \sqrt{-121}}$ and showed that $\sqrt[3]{2 \pm \sqrt{-121}} = 2 \pm \sqrt{-1}$ which gives $x = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $u$ and $v$ are such that $u^3+v^3=-q$ and that $3uv=-p$. You already know that then $u+v$ is a root of the depressed equation. On the other hand, $u^3$ and $v^3$ are the roots of a quadratic equation with real coefficients and without real roots; it follows that $v^3=\overline{u^3}=\overline u^3$ and that therefore, $v=\overline u$, $v=\omega\overline u$ or $v=\omega^2\overline u$. But, since $3uv=-p\in\Bbb R$, then in fact, you can't have $v=\omega\overline u$ and neither can you have $v=\omega^2\overline u$. Conclusion: $y=\overline u$.

If $u=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$, then $v=\overline u=r(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)$, and so $u+v=2\cos\theta$.

Now, let $u'=\omega u$ and let $v'=\omega^2v$. Then $u'^3+v'^3=-q$ and $3u'v'=-p$. So, $u'+v'$ is also a root of the cubic. But\begin{align}u'+v'&=(r\cos\theta+ri\sin\theta)\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)+\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)i\right)+\\&\ +(r\cos(-\theta)+ri\sin(-\theta))\left(\cos\left(\frac{-2\pi}3\right)+\sin\left(-\frac{2\pi}3\right)i\right)\\&=2r\cos\left(\theta+\frac{2\pi}3\right).\end{align}

Finally, if you take $u''=\omega^2u$ and $v''=\omega v$, you can deduce that $2r\cos\left(\theta+\frac{4\pi}3\right)$ is still another root of your cubic.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w(\alpha) = \cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha$. Then
$$w(\alpha) w(\beta) = (\cos\alpha + i \sin \alpha)(\cos \beta + i\sin \beta) \\ =\cos\alpha \cos \beta - \sin \alpha \sin \beta +i(\cos\alpha \sin \beta + \sin \alpha \cos \beta) = \cos(\alpha + \beta) + i \sin(\alpha + \beta) \\= w(\alpha + \beta) .$$
An easier way to see this is to write $w(\alpha) = e^{i\alpha}$. Then
$$w(\alpha) w(\beta) = e^{i\alpha}e^{i\beta} = e^{i(\alpha + \beta)} = w(\alpha + \beta) .$$

We have
$$u\omega = rw(\theta)w(\phi) = rw(\theta+\phi) ,$$
$$u\omega^2 = rw(\theta)w(2\phi) = rw(\theta+2\phi) .$$
Moreover, since $v = \overline u$ and $\omega^2 = \overline \omega$, we get
$$v\omega^2 = \overline u \cdot \overline \omega = \overline{u\omega} ,$$
thus
$$u\omega + v\omega^2 = 2\Re (u\omega) = 2r\cos(\theta + \phi) = 2r\cos(\theta + 2\pi/3) .$$
Similarly
$$v\omega = \overline u \cdot \overline {\omega^2} = \overline{u\omega^2},$$
thus
$$u\omega^2 +  v\omega = 2\Re (u\omega^2) = 2r\cos(\theta + 2\phi) = 2r\cos(\theta + 4\pi/3) .$$

**Edited:**

In my opinion it is an odd aproach to apply Cardano's formula and then translate the result into a trigonometric form. A direct approach is via  *angle trisection*. By Moivre's formula we have
$$\cos\phi + i\sin\phi = (\cos(\phi/3) + i\sin(\phi/3))^3$$
which gives
$$\cos \phi = \cos^3(\phi/3) -3\cos(\phi/3)\sin^2(\phi/3)\\  = \cos^3(\phi/3) -3\cos(\phi/3)(1- \cos^2(\phi/3)) = 4 \cos^3(\phi/3) - 3 \cos(\phi/3) .$$
Writing $\theta = \phi/3$ and $x = 2\cos \theta$ gives us the cubic *angle trisection equation*
$$x^3 - 3x =  2\cos \phi \tag{1}.$$
By construction it has the obvious solution $x_0 = 2\cos \theta$. But since $\cos \phi = \cos (\phi + 2\pi) = \cos (\phi + 4 \pi)$, it also has the solutions $x_1 = 2 \cos((\phi + 2\pi)/3) = 2\cos (\theta + 2\pi/3)$, $x_2 = 2 \cos((\phi + 4\pi)/3) = 2\cos (\theta + 4\pi/3)$.

Under the assumption that $p, q$ are real and $D = 27q^2 + 4 p^3<0$ it is possible to reduce the general equation
$$t^3 + pt + q = 0 \tag{2}$$
to the angle trisection equation (1). Since $D < 0$, we must have $p < 0$. Note that therefore $D < 0$ is equivalent to  $27q^2/(-4p^3) < 1$.

Let us write $t = cx$. Then
$$x^3 + (p/c^2)x = -q/c^3 .$$
With $c = \sqrt{-p/3} > 0$ we get
$$x^3 -3x = 2(-q/2c^3) .$$
But
$$(-q/2c^3)^2 = q^2 /4(-p/3)^3 = 27q^2/(-4p^3) < 1$$
which means that
$$-q/2c^3 \in (-1,1) .$$
Therefore $\phi = \arccos(-q/2c^3)$ is a well-defined number in $(0,2\pi)$ and we get the cubic equation (1) with solutions $x_k$ as above. Therefore the solutions of (2) are
$$t_k = 2\sqrt{-p/3}\cos(\phi/3 + 2k\pi/3) , k = 0,1,2 .$$

Comment: Also see my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2838797.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way to see the algebra beyond the solution of the cubic. It is based on the known algebraic identity:
$$
\tag{$*$}
t^3+x^3+y^3-3txy 
=(t+x+y)(t+\omega x+\omega^2y)(t+\omega^2 x+\omega y)\ .
$$
Then with the notations from the OP, taking $x,y$ to be $-u,-v$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
0
&=t^3+pt+q\\
&=t^3-3tuv-x^3-y^3\\
&=(t-u-v)(t-\omega u-\omega^2 v)(t-\omega^2 u+\omega v)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So the roots of the cubic are $u\omega^k + v\omega^{2k}=u\omega^k + v\bar\omega^k$, for $k$ among $0,1,2$.

Now consider $u,v$ to be $r(\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta)$. Then the root $u+v$ is immediately seen to be $2r\cos \theta$.

The other two are equally simple, for instance:
$$
\begin{aligned}
u\omega +v\bar\omega
&=
r(\cos\theta+ i\sin\theta)(\cos(2\pi/3)+ i\sin(2\pi/3))
\\
&\ +
r(\cos\theta- i\sin\theta)(\cos(2\pi/3)- i\sin(2\pi/3))
\\[2mm]
&=
r(\cos(\theta+2\pi/3) + i\sin(\theta+2\pi/3))
\\
&\ +
r(\cos(-\theta-2\pi/3) + i\sin(-\theta-2\pi/3))
\\[2mm]
&=
2r\cos(\theta+2\pi/3)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can "brute force" the solution of the quadratic,

$$x^2+qx-\frac{p^3}{27}=0,$$

giving two roots

$$u^3,v^3=\frac{-q\pm\sqrt{q^2+\dfrac{4p^3}{27}}}2$$ which are complex. In polar form,

$$\rho=\frac{q^2}2+\frac{p^3}{27}$$ and $$\theta=\pm\arctan\sqrt{1+\dfrac{4p^3}{27q^2}}+k\pi.$$

Now after taking the cubic roots,

$$u+v=\sqrt[3]\rho\left(\cos\frac\theta3+i\sin\frac\theta3+\cos\frac\theta3-i\sin\frac\theta3\right)=2\sqrt[3]\rho\cos\frac\theta3$$ for $k=0,1,2$.

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative method:**

We can try to turn
$$t^3+pt+q=0$$
into
$$4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta=a$$ by a change of variable: we set

$$t=\lambda \cos\theta$$ and solve

$$-\frac3{4\lambda^2}=p,$$ or

$$\lambda=\sqrt{-\frac3{4p}}.$$ This establishes

$$4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta=-4q\lambda^3.$$

But the LHS is just

$$\cos3\theta.$$