# Solving Special Case of Cubic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

Given a cubic equation of standard form $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0$ where $a, b, c, d$ are real numbers, if we know that there is only one real root $x_r$, we know $x_r>0$, and we only care about finding $x_r$ (ie. we don't care about solving for the other two roots), is there an easier/better way to find that single root than using the Cardano method or some numerical approximation?

Thanks!

Edit: For clarity, looking for an equation for $x_r$ in terms of the coefficients, by "easier" I mean smallest number of operations but can be in a sequence of functions or trigonometric, essentially looking for anything that has fewer operations than Cardano

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ real numbers?

Comment: @Andrei a, b, c, d are real numbers, edited question!

Comment: Well, you need to specify what do you consider "find"? Do you need an expression in radicals in terms of the coefficients or in trigonometric function, or a convergent sequence of rational functions of the coefficients? What do you consider "easier"? Is is having an expression with the the smallest number of operations, smallest number of radicals, smallest number of transcendental operations, or a sequence converging faster?

Comment: @user85667 edited for clarity! Essentially looking for an equation/process for $x_r$  in terms of the coefficients with smallest number of operations

Comment: If you are planning to implement it, yes, don't use Cardano. You can do [Newton's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) starting from an [upper **and** lower bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots) of the roots.

Comment: @user85667 yeah have thought about that, more curious if there's an analytical solution that doesn't involve numerical approximations given the constraints (ie. known there is only one real positive root) that is "simpler" than cardano

Comment: Can elementary differential and integral calculus be used?

Comment: There are various approaches to solve cubic equations, but I doubt that you find the "silver bullet". See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3773856 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2838797.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for roots of a cubic equation having real coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ in form of an equation or some mathematical expression, then you have to resort to using the formulae of Cardano and Vieta. @ClaudeLeibovici has already answered your question using that method. Here is another way to calculate only the sought real root of a cubic equation using an expression containing radicals.

Assuming $a\neq 0$, we divide the given cubic equation by $a$ to obtain,
$$x^3+\beta x^2+\gamma x+\delta=0.$$

First we calculate two quantities $m$ and $n$ as shown below. They are supposed to facilitate the presentation of our solution.
$$m=\dfrac{\gamma}{3}-\dfrac{\beta^2}{9}$$
$$n=\dfrac{\beta^3}{27}-\dfrac{\beta\gamma}{6}+\dfrac{\delta}{2}$$

If you examine the expressions given for $m$ and $n$, you will notice that $m=\dfrac{p}{3}$ and $n=\dfrac{q}{2}$, where $p$ and $q$ are defined in @ClaudeLeibovici’s answer.

Now, we are in a position to write down the equation for the one and only real root as a function of $m$ and $n$.
$$x_\text{real root}=\sqrt[3]{-n+\sqrt{n^2+m^3}}-\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n^2+m^3}}-\dfrac{\beta}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better method to solve the cubic equation
$$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0$$
To simplify, assuming $a\neq 0$, divide all coefficients by $a$ and consider
$$x^3+\beta x^2+\gamma x +\delta=0$$ Define
$$p=\gamma -\frac{\beta ^2}{3}\qquad \text{and}\qquad q=\frac{2 \beta ^3}{27}-\frac{\beta  \gamma }{3}+\delta$$and, using the hyperbolic method for one real root
$$\color{blue}{x_r=-2\frac{|q|}{q}\sqrt{-\frac{p}{3}}\cosh\left[\frac{1}{3}\operatorname{arcosh}\left(\frac{-3|q|}{2p}\sqrt{\frac{-3}{p}}\right)\right]-\frac \beta 3}\qquad \color{red}{\text{if}\qquad p <0}$$
$$\color{blue}{x_r= -2\sqrt{\frac{p}{3}}\sinh\left[\frac{1}{3}\operatorname{arsinh}\left(\frac{3q}{2p}\sqrt{\frac{3}{p}}\right)\right]-\frac \beta 3}\qquad \color{red}{\text{if}\qquad p >0}$$

Comment: Correct, but why do you think this solution is much better than the Cardano solution in YNK's answer?

Comment: @PaulFrost. This is a subjective opinion : more elegant would be better. Cheers :-)

Comment: @PaulFrost Let me first ask your permission to state my opinion about your comment. 
When Claude Leibovic wrote "There is a much better method to solve the cubic equation" at the top of his answer, which was posted $\bf{\text{two days before}}$ I did mine, he did compare his answer with a method suggested by OP, not with mine.

Answer (score 1):

If elementary differential calculus can be used we can take help of graph of cubic to obtain  a single real root $x_r$.

The graph appears like a rocket course that initially begins to plummet for $a>0$  but recovers to rise again. ( For $a<0$ the order is reversed with first plummet, rise and plummet again).

In doing so the graph  should keep $(y_{max}/y_{min})$ both  above or both  below  the x-axis with a single intersection at $x_r$, so that their product is positive.

The  constant coefficient $d$ influences by entire cubic graph $y$ shifting up or down, so I have included here elementary min/max differential calculus.

$$ y(x)=ax^4+bx^2+cx+d \tag 1$$

Its graph should cut x-axis only once. Maximum/minimum values $y(x_1), y(x_2)$ at roots $(x_1,x_2)$ of parabola are found by differentiation.

$$ \frac{dy(x)}{dx}=3ax^2+2bx+c=0 $$

$$(x_1,x_2)= \left(\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-3ac }}{3a},\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-3ac}}{3a}\right) $$

The clue to find determinant for single intersection $x_r$  of graph is when extrema are on same side of x-axis ( here red and green ), i.e., ***discriminant for single $x_r$***

$$ \Delta= y(x_1)\cdot y(x_2)>0$$

For three intersections/real roots the discriminant
$$ \Delta<0$$

and for a single root and a double root that has tangential contact with x-axis we have

$$ \Delta=0$$

By simplification we find the discriminant

$$\boxed{\Delta=\frac{a(4c^3+27ad^2)+b(4b^2d -bc^2-18acd)}{27 a^2}}$$

It can be derived with Cardano formulae but believe it would be more cumbersome to go around and express it in terms of given $(a,b,c,d)$.

[image]

Plots generated for cubic coefficients $(a,b,c)=(.2,-0.4,-1)$, $d =(3,\approx 2.01213,1,-1)$ for four cubics shown above.

A a unique single root/ numerical solution of (1) can be obtained  ***subject to condition $\Delta>0 $*** satisfied by given coefficients