# How to analytically find the root of $x^3+3x^2-5x-16$?

Tags: polynomials, roots

This is part of solving the problem posed in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUZrAXc5MdY&t=338s).

I can numerically determine that the real root is about 2.27, but I am wondering how I can find an exact representation of the root.

Comment: You can try Cardan's method to find roots of a cubic polynomial.

Comment: The only analytical approach that I know of for the generic cubic is discussed in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation).

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2B3x%5E2%E2%88%925x%E2%88%9216%3D0

Comment: try Newton-Raphson method

Comment: See the answer at: [Is there really analytic solution to cubic equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838797/is-there-really-analytic-solution-to-cubic-equation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the steps described in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation), using the hyperbolic method for one real root, you should find
$$x=4 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{27
   }{32}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\right)-1$$

Comment: wow, I did not expect it to be so complex.