# Can't find the polynomial root

Tags: systems-of-equations

For which values ​​of the parameter $m$, square trinomial $f(x)=mx^2+(m+1)x+1$ has two different roots such that:

$x_1^3-x_2^3=x_1^4-x_2^4$ (the value of the parameter $m$ should be approximated).

After calculating this condition (using Viete) $x_1^3-x_2^3=x_1^4-x_2^4$, I've received this equation: $2m^3+2m^2+2m+1=0$.
The problem is I don't know how to find the polynomial roots of this equation.I know that  it should be $\approx-0.65$, but I don't know how to solve it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "*using Viete*" $\;-\;$ You could also use use that $\,\{x_1,x_2\} = \{-1, -1/m\}\,$ directly.

Comment: $P(-1)=-1$ and $P(0)=1$. You can use these values to start regula falsi or Newton's iterations.

Comment: You can use the Cardano formula. See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2838797 .

Answer (score 1):

$$2m^3+2m^2+2m+1=0$$

Following the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation), you have $\Delta=-44$; so, there is only one real root.

Using the [hyperbolic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root), you will obtain
$$m=-\frac{1}{3} \left(1+2 \sqrt{2} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{13}{8\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\right)=-0.647799\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:

$$1 + x_1 + x_1^2 = (1+x_2)(1+x_2^2)$$

$$ x_1+x_2= \frac{-(m+1)}{m}$$

$$ x_1 x_2= \frac{1}{m}$$

Comment: OP has already found the $m$ polynomial (and a first root).

Comment: Hi Professor.  How  come your account appears fresh my computer has a problem?

Comment: Don't worry, I am just reborn.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Or reputation is displayed mod. 1,000,000 ...

Comment: @PaulFrost: :-D