Having trouble with the complex solutions of $ x^3+7x^2+15x+15=0 $
I am trying to solve $$ x^3+7x^2+15x+15=0 $$. The real solution was not an issue. However, the complex solutions driving me mad.
I was able to express the real solution as $$ x=(1/3) \left (-7+\sqrt[3]{-73+9\sqrt{65}}+\sqrt[3]{-73-9\sqrt{65}}  \right ). $$ I managed to manipulate the cube roots as $$ \sqrt[3]{-73+9\sqrt{65}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{73-9\sqrt{65}}+i\sqrt{3}\sqrt[3]{73-9\sqrt{65}}}{2} $$ and
$$\sqrt[3]{-73-9\sqrt{65}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{73+9\sqrt{65}}+i\sqrt{3}\sqrt[3]{73+9\sqrt{65}}}{2}. $$
Substituting these complex values for the cube roots in my original expression for $x$  yields the correct real part, but the incorrect imaginary part. I do know that if I simply move the $ \sqrt{3} $ from the numerator to the denominator, then it does yield the correct imaginary part. I am at a complete loss as to how this shift occurs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

@Distilled Ink: The usual reduction for disappear the second degree term can be simplificated by the form $(3x+7)^3-12(3x+7)+146$ so you can solve the standard way the equation $X^3-12X+146=0$ where it is clear what $X$ is.

Are you remembering that each cube root has three possible values?

@Piquito I absolutely should be approaching it that way. However, I am stubbornly interested in how the complex roots pop out of the general cubic formula expressed in terms of a, b, c, and d. I'm in too deep to quit now.

@Ted Chifrin I have been thinking about that, but clearly not in the correct way. Perhaps another cup of coffee will help. Thank you!

Perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2838797/349785 helps.

For the real root, it will be simpler to use the hyperbolic solution to obtain
$$x_1=-\frac{1}{3} \left(7+4 \cosh\left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{73}{8}\right)\right)\right)$$
Writing
$$x^3+7x^2+15x+15=(x-x_1)(x^2+b x+c)$$ leads to
$$b=x_1+7\qquad \text{and} \qquad c=-\frac {15}{x_1}$$
Solve the quadratic equation.
