# Cube root of $-2+i$

Tags: polynomials, problem-solving, cubics, nested-radicals

**Edit:**
My question comes from finding the solutions of this equation using Cardano's method(because our teacher said :D ):
$$x^3-6x+4=0$$
And finally I got:
$$x=(\sqrt[3]{2})\sqrt[3]{-2+\sqrt{-1}}⠀+(\sqrt[3]2)\sqrt[3]{-2-\sqrt{-1}}$$
**I want to denest and find the cube roots of this two radicals.**

According to this links answers:
[First link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155/strategies-to-denest-nested-radicals-sqrtab-sqrtc)
[Second link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871639/denesting-radicals-like-sqrt3-sqrt32-1?rq=1)
[Third link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2836570/cube-root-of-numbers-such-as-211i?rq=1)
I tried to find this using **norm**(actually for dinest):
$$\sqrt[3]{-2+i}$$
So the **problem's norm is $5$** and I must find a root with **norm = $\sqrt[3]{5}$**  .

And I found this :
$$(\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{5}⠀-1}⠀+i)$$
But:
$$(\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{5}⠀-1}⠀+i)^3\neq {-2+i}$$

Anybody can tell me whats my wrong?
And how to correct that?

Comment: Norm is $\sqrt{(-2)^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{5}.$

Comment: @user2661923 Added more informatin.

Comment: @user2661923 I saw that but we ought solve this with Cardano's method only.

Comment: For what its worth, I deleted my answer in favor of Henno Brandsma's 2nd answer, which I upvoted.  See my trailing comment to his answer, which gives $\cos(\pi/12)$ and $\sin(\pi/12)$.  When I was verifying part of his work, I used that $$(2 + \sqrt{3})(\sqrt{3} - 1)^2 = (2 + \sqrt{3})(4 - 2\sqrt{3}) = 2 \implies \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}~~(\sqrt{3} - 1) = \sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: @user2661923 We're not able to know what exactly C numbers mean.We also consider$\sqrt{-1}$ as an abstract thing . In our class examples , the teacher used "guessing" for the cube roots. We cannot use cos or sin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying Cardano's method to $x^3- 6x+4 =0$ I get:

set $x=u+v$, then

$$x^3 = u^3 + v^3 +3uv(u+v)$$

$$-6x = -6(u+v)$$

so in order  to cancel the last terms we set $uv=2$.

So the equation transforms into

$$u^3 + v^3 + 4 = 0; uv=2 $$

Using $v = \frac{2}{u}$ we get

$$u^3 + \frac{8}{u^3} + 4 =0$$

and we set $t = u^3$ and multiply both sides by $t$ to get

$$t^2 + 4t + 8 = 0 \to (t+2)^2 + 4  =0$$

And so $$t+2 = 2i \to t = 2i-2 \text{ or } t+2 = -2i \to t = -2i -2$$

This doesn't seem to lead to your solution?

**Added** $x=2$ is a solution (the only rational roots are integer divisors of $4$), and the equation factorises to $$(x-2)(x^2 +2x-2)=0$$

Comment: @user2661923 We get a third root of $2(i-1)$ and one of $-2(i+1)$ which is close but not equal to what the OP had. Unless I made a calculation mistake.

Comment: @user2661923 These are the $t$ but then use $t= u^3, uv=2$ etc and the original equation has $x=u+v$ as root, not $t$!

Comment: It just hit me; $(x = 2)$ is a root of the equation.

Comment: @user2661923 Indeed a divisor of $4$ as expected.

Comment: @user2661923 One root is $x=\sqrt[3]{2i-2} + \frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{2i-2}}$. Simplify...

Comment: +1 to your answer, which I was finally able to follow.  Since the argument of $(1 + i)$ is $(\pi/4)$ and since $\cos(\pi/6) = (\sqrt{3}/2)$ I was able to use (1/2 angle formulas) to compute $$\cos(\pi/12) = (1/2)\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}$$ and $$\sin(\pi/12) = (1/2)\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: For irreducible cubics, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis  I guess this example is exempt because it reduces over the rationals...

Comment: @WillJagy it factors over the reals but not over the rationals. It’s the \Delta>0$ in the casus link.

Comment: I meant your reduction of the original cubic $(x-2)(x^2 +2x-2).$  If we have a cubic that is irreducible over the rationals and has three distinct real roots, we get in a circular mess because we need cube roots of non-real numbers for Cardano, and each such cube root leads to more casus irreducibles. Never ends.

Comment: Well, examples of that, irreducible but with nice roots (sums of cosines of $2\pi/n$  for $n=7$ or $n=9$)  are $x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1$  for seven, then $x^3 - 3 x + 1$ for nine. These examples show up on this site from time to time.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks for the answering effort ,but I was already know that what actually the answers is(e.g 2,...). But the problem is how to denest my cube radicals.This is all I want(even through guessing ).

Answer (score 1):

The given number can be presented in the forms of
$$-2+i=\sqrt5e^{i\varphi}=\sqrt5\left(\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi\right),$$
where
$$\cos\varphi = -\dfrac2{\sqrt5},\quad \sin\varphi=\dfrac1{\sqrt5},\quad \tan\dfrac\varphi2 = \dfrac{\sin\varphi}{1+\cos\varphi}=\dfrac1{\sqrt5-2}=\sqrt5+2,$$
$$\varphi=2\arctan(\sqrt5+2)\approx2.678.\tag1$$
Taking in account the periodicity
$$\sqrt5e^{i\varphi} = \sqrt5e^{i\varphi+2i\pi} = \sqrt5e^{i\varphi-2i\pi},$$
one can get three different values of the required cubic root in the form of
$$\sqrt[3]{-2+i}\,=\sqrt[6]5e^{i\large\frac{\varphi+2\pi k}3}, k=0,1,-1.\tag2$$
Then, for example,
$$\sqrt[6]5e^{i\large\frac{2\arctan(5+\sqrt2)}3}\approx0.82036+1.01832i.$$

Using of the half-argument in the tangent function allows to avoid problems with the quadrant accounting.

Answer (score 0):

$-2+i$ has norm (length) equal to $\sqrt{(-2)^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{5}=5^{\frac12}$.
So the norm of a cube root of it must have norm $(5^{\frac12})^{\frac13} = 5^{\frac16} = \sqrt[6]{5}$.

Now look at the argument of $-2+i$ and take a third of it.

Comment: It seems to $i^2=-1$ .Am I wrong?

Comment: @program_craft $i^2=-1$ is true by definition, but how is it relevant ?

Comment: @user2661923 We don't need an exact answer as a radical do we? We can use arctan etc. That way you at least get an approximate answer.

Comment: @program_craft what? the norm of $a+bi$ is just the square root of $a^2 + b^2$. Pythagoras and all that..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma take a look at this 50+ answer [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/196181/831100)

Comment: @program_craft You're not denesting anything here, but you want a cube root of some complex number. Different problem.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yeah I wanna dinest that. Its possible?

Comment: @user2661923 I've already mentioned the tags that related to this like (nested-radicals) ...but your right.I edited the question and added more details.

Comment: @user2661923 actually I wanted to make the question shorter.Ok you want more explaination about the source and the problem?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think that the very first comment from the OP means that he's considering this as denesting $\sqrt[3]{-2+\sqrt{-1}}$  I don't know anything about this, but a short perusal of the linked answers on denesting seems to indicate that they apple to real fields.

Comment: @user2661923 Cardano method? The equation is in the right form.